# Passing a structure of parameters to a Level 1 m-code S-function in Simulink

Tags: matlab, parameters, simulink, s-function

I am trying to pass a structure of parameters to an S-function in MATLAB. I have a bunch of parameters and I would like to avoid passing them like this:

%   The general form of an MATLAB S-function syntax is:
%       [SYS,X0,STR,TS,SIMSTATECOMPLIANCE] = SFUNC(T,X,U,FLAG,P1,...,Pn)

I would prefer passing a single structure that includes all of my parameters. I loaded the data into the Model Workspace as:
[image]

First I tried ( in response to Phil):

function [sys,x0,str,ts,simStateCompliance]=system1(t,x,u,flag,DATA_HMMWV)

sizes.NumInputs      = 2;

also,

[image: with the Simulink looking like:]

But I get this error:

[image]

Phil, this is why I tried to add another input port to the S-Function, I thought that it had to go in there.

I also tried:
sizes.NumInputs      = 1;

and I get this error:
[image]

Also, are you sure that the DATA_HMMWV is a parameter? It looks slightly different than a Param in this window:
[image]

NEW:::: 1/25/2016

Phil, the issue is not with my derivative function, the issue is that I am still not passing the structure into the function. Here is a picture. Notice the data is in the Model Workspace and I passed it (DATA_HMMWV) to the function, but when I stop the simulation at line 13 (debugging mode), DATA_HMMWV is not in the function workspace.

[image]

If the code continues ( to flag = 1) we get:
[image]

If the code continues to run, it crashes with this error:
[image]

So, there were not enough input arguments passed to the function. Also, the function is very simple:

%
function sys = mdlDerivatives(t,x,u,DATA_HMMWV)

sys = DATA_HMMWV.g;

% end mdlDerivatives

It just tries to grab a parameter from the structure.

Comment: You should really be writing a level 2 S-Function, not a level 1 S-Function.  For the level-1 syntax, your `P1` variable should be the same datatype as the the variable you pass, so just pass in the structure as an input.  (For level 2 S-Functions you'll need to learn how to use Bus Objects.)

Comment: Phil, thank you very much for your suggestions. I will look into the level 2 S-function, but for now ( in order to avoid making too many modifications to a very complicated code that I have inherited ) I will try your second suggestion. I have actually been trying to pass the structure as an input, but I have not been able to make it work. Once I define the data in the model workspace ( as in my picture above), how to I feed it into the S-function?

Comment: In Simulink there is a very clear distinction between a _signal_ (which is fed into a block via  an input port) and a _parameter_ (which is specified on a block dialog).  Your `DATA_HMMVW` is a parameter.  Double click on the S-Function block and enter the variable name in the S-Function Parameters line of the dialog.

Comment: Phil, thank you for your help. I updated my post again to respond to your comment. Basically, I tired to do what you suggested already, but it was giving me an error.

Comment: It looks like you should be using `NumInputs = 1'.  For the error related to the Derivative at t=0 you'll need to show us (some of) your code, specifically: how the derivatives function is actually being called, and what it is expecting.

Comment: Thank you for your assistance with this. Unfortunately, I am still struggling to make this work.( I updated my post with more information). When this is resolved, I will try and clean up this post.

Comment: The screenshot you show is for flag = 0.  What does it look like for flag = 1?

Comment: I just updated it. Thanks very much!

Comment: Show us a picture of the S-Function dialog too.  Is DATA_HMMVW listed in the S-Function Parameters part of the dialog?

Comment: Also, note that this parameter is _not_ a Simulink.Parameters object, which is what you show the variable `Param` as being in one of your images.  They are different things (and Simulink.Parameter objects have nothing to do with your problem).

Comment: Phil, thank you very much. You figured it out! I did not set up my Block Parameters. I am not sure how I missed this. You answered my question. I wanted to make a clear demonstration of the steps to show how to do this for anyone that would like to do it in the future. Should I do this in my original post and delete my debugging process or should I put it in the (Answer Your Question ) box? I just did not want to take credit for this because you are the one that figured it out.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setup 1: Load the data as a structure into the base workspace and run the simulink model

```
clear;
clc;
close all
PlantName = 'untitled';
open(PlantName)
TFinal          = 10;
load DATA_HMMWV.mat
sim(PlantName, TFinal)
```

Setup 2:
[image: level 1 S-function that is being called in simulink]

Setup 3:
When you double click on this model, specify the structure that you would like to pass to the S-function as:
[image]

Setup 4: your functions should also have the structure in it:

```
function [sys,x0,str,ts,simStateCompliance]=system1(t,x,u,flag,DATA_HMMWV)
```

and any other functions that you need the structure in, for example:

```
  case 1
sys = mdlDerivatives(t,x,u,DATA_HMMWV);
```

then,

```
function sys = mdlDerivatives(t,x,u,DATA_HMMWV)
```

Now, you have passed a strucure to level-1 S-function!